# How to return variable itself from a PHP functions intead of returning the values?

Tags: php, function, return

I have several variables which I define in a helper function (`value` below). I want to get all those variables from the `value` function by somehow returning them. How can I do this?

```
<?php
function value()
{
    $var1 = 1;
    $var2 = 2;
    $var3 = 3;
    $var4 = 4;
    $var5 = 5;

    /*I want to return the variables themselves instead of the value of the 
    variables*/
}
?>
```

Comment: No idea what you're asking. Perhaps give us an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: What do you mean with “returning variables”?

Comment: You can declare those variables as global.

Comment: Do you mean return variable name instead of value?

Comment: Examples ALWAYS help us to understand what you are asking. They dont have to be the real code but they should be representative of the situation you are asking about

Comment: @RahulMeshram Globals should only EVER be a last resort

Comment: I think you need to refer this http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: Saad Suri yes! i need to echo all these variables in a different places so i decided to put up a function where it will assign the designated values to the variables. but php functions only returns the values

Comment: You could return an array instead, or pass which variable name you wish the value from as a function arg and return the relevant value. Or have different functions for each value. But I still don't really understand what your use case is.

Comment: oh yeah, i guess i could use an array to put all the values instead of assigning them one by one into an individual variable then i could just echo the array with a specific index that contains the value i want! thanks! i got it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it in an array and then get the array keys. Array keys here refer to your variables in your question.

```
    function value() {
      $arr = array('var1' => 1, 'var2' => 2, 'var3' => 3);
      return array_keys($arr);
    }

$variables_names = value();
```

Then loop through the return array which contains only the keys (variables names), not the value.

```
foreach ($variables_names as $name) {
  echo $name;
}
```